# AWS showing it's own error screen even when the error handler exists in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.type === 'entity.too.large')
        res.send(
            '<p align="center">Please upload an image below the defined limit of 5 MB. <br> Click <a href="/create">here</a> to visit the upload page again.</p>'
        )
    else res.redirect('/')
})
```

I have this code to catch the errors. But AWS still shows this instead of the intended text.

The app is hosted in an EC2 instance of Elastic Beanstalk.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create `proxy.conf` file with the below folder structure.
Root should have .platform folder.

```
.platform\nginx\conf.d\proxy.conf
```

And inside root folder paste this code.

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

Comment: Do you mean to paste the code in the `proxy.config` file?

Comment: @AnshAgarwal Yes.